# How can I manage units in pandas data?

Tags: python, pandas, units-of-measurement, custom-formatting

I'm trying to figure out if there is a good way to manage *units* in my pandas data. For example, I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
   length (m)  width (m)  thickness (cm)
0         1.2        3.4             5.6
1         7.8        9.0             1.2
2         3.4        5.6             7.8
```

Currently, the measurement units are encoded in column names. Downsides include:

1. column selection is awkward -- `df['width (m)']` vs. `df['width']`
2. things will likely break if the units of my source data change

If I wanted to strip the units out of the column names, is there somewhere else that the information could be stored?

Comment: I think the best way would be to store it in a Series / dictionary. If you want to somehow link these two, you can add an attribute (`df.units = pd.Series({'length' : 'm', 'width': 'm', 'thickness': 'cm'})`) -- This may be dangerous though.

Comment: I didn't want to add a full answer since it's not Pandas, but the Astropy package can do this within its `Table`  and `units` module, you can move over from DataFrame to Astropy Table (`atab=astropy.table.Table.from_pandas(df)`), and then give each column a unit (e.g. `atab['length'].unit = astropy.units.m`). I can post a mwe if you are interested, it looks too messy as a comment with lots of code.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you could use astropy tables to get the functionality of a dataframe-like that can handle units.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There isn't any great way to do this right now, see github issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10349) for some discussion.

As a quick hack, could do something like this, maintaining a separate dict with the units.

```
In [3]: units = {}

In [5]: newcols = []
   ...: for col in df:
   ...:     name, unit = col.split(' ')
   ...:     units[name] = unit
   ...:     newcols.append(name)

In [6]: df.columns = newcols

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   length  width  thickness
0     1.2    3.4        5.6
1     7.8    9.0        1.2
2     3.4    5.6        7.8

In [8]: units['length']
Out[8]: '(m)'
```

Comment: What if they just have something like a dtype but for arbitrary units?

Answer (score 16):

As I was searching for this, too. Here is what [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and the (experimental) [pint_pandas](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pint-pandas.html?highlight=pandas) is capable of today:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pint
import pint_pandas

ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
ureg.Unit.default_format = "~P"
pint_pandas.PintType.ureg.default_format = "~P"

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "length": pd.Series([1.2, 7.8, 3.4], dtype="pint[m]"),
    "width": pd.Series([3.4, 9.0, 5.6], dtype="pint[m]"),
    "thickness": pd.Series([5.6, 1.2, 7.8], dtype="pint[cm]"),
})

print(df.pint.dequantify())
```

```
     length width thickness
unit      m     m        cm
0       1.2   3.4       5.6
1       7.8   9.0       1.2
2       3.4   5.6       7.8
```

```py
df['width'] = df['width'].pint.to("inch")

print(df.pint.dequantify())
```

```
     length       width thickness
unit      m          in        cm
0       1.2  133.858268       5.6
1       7.8  354.330709       1.2
2       3.4  220.472441       7.8
```

Comment: pint_pandas is indeed nice, but the package still comes with many issues, which makes it quite cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 3):

Offer you some methods:

1. pands-units-extension: [janpipek/pandas-units-extension: Units extension array for pandas based on astropy](https://github.com/janpipek/pandas-units-extension)
2. pint-pandas: [hgrecco/pint-pandas: Pandas support for pint](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint-pandas)

you can also extend the pandas by yourself following this [Extending pandas — pandas 1.3.0 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html)